# Installing SSL on Amazon EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install a SSL on my EC2 instance but I'm having issues.

I've uploaded it via CLI, and when I do list-server-certificates I see that it's been installed correctly.

But when I check the SSL info, it still shows the info from the old expired certificate.

Does anyone know what step I might have missed?

Comment: What server application do you want presenting the certificate, and what language is it written in?

Comment: Are you installing an SSL certificate within your web server or on an elastic load balancer?